# best way to index by value of the header in a 2d list

Tags: python, list, csv

This solution sort of works but is extremely ugly:

[Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

```
rowIndex = 3
sheet = list(csv.reader(open('ObserverLog.csv'))) 
print sheet[rowIndex][sheet[0].index("Message sent? (Y/N)")]
```

It seems like there ought to be a way to make it work like this:

```
print sheet[rowIndex]["Message sent? (Y/N)"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DictReader` will read each row as a dictionary:

```
list(csv.DictReader(open('ObserverLog.csv')))
```

Returns a list of dictionary, so

```
sheet[rowIndex]["Message sent? (Y/N)"]
```

would work.

Comment: This works well enough. not totally what I wanted but it is exactly what I asked for. haha.   An unanticipated consequence of this is I can't reference by index anymore. but that's OK.

Comment: @gnarbarian Well if you really want to have all the power you can try using pandas, which is great :-)